# How to solve icon toggle on add/remove to favourite in React

Tags: reactjs, icons, toggle, favorites

Hey there i am having some trouble when adding/deleting a favourite. When i toggle the heart icon it does what it is supposed to in the backend, so it adds or it removes correctly an item from the favourites. The issue is that if i add an item to favourites, the icon becomes a full heart, which is right, but if i remove an item from the favourites, all the icons toggle back to an empty heart, although the removal of the single item worked, but only refreshing the page will display exactly which are favourites with the full heart. Any idea of what is the issue?
this is the code:

```
<span className={classes.heart_div}>
{
      favourite && favourite.filter(fav => fav._id === property._id).length > 0
       ?
       <i className={`${filledHeart} ${classes.heartIcon}`} onClick={() => deleteFavourite(property._id)}></i>
       :
       <i className="ri-heart-line favorite" onClick={() => postFavourite(property._id)}></i>                    
}
</span>
```

Redux postFavourite and deleteFavourite

```
export const postFavourite = (propertyId) => (dispatch) => {

    const bearer = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')

    return fetch(baseUrl + 'my-favourites/' + propertyId, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({"_id": propertyId}),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            'Authorization': bearer
        },
        credentials: 'same-origin'
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response
        }
        else {
            var error = new Error('Error ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText)
            error.response = response
            throw error
        }
    },
    error => {
        throw error;
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(favourites =>  dispatch(addFavourites(favourites) ))
    .catch(error => dispatch(favouritesFailed(error.message)))
}

export const deleteFavourite = (propertyId) => (dispatch) => {

    const bearer = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')

    return fetch(baseUrl + 'my-favourites/' + propertyId, {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {
          'Authorization': bearer
        },
        credentials: "same-origin"
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response
        } else {
          var error = new Error('Error ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText)
          error.response = response
          throw error
        }
      },
      error => {
            throw error
      })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(favourites =>  dispatch(addFavourites(favourites)) )
    .catch(error => dispatch(favouritesFailed(error.message)))
}
```

this is the reducer

```
import * as ActionTypes from './ActionTypes'

export const Favourites = (state = {
    isLoading: true,
    errMess: null,
    favourites: []
}, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.ADD_FAVOURITES:
            return {...state, isLoading: false, errMess: null, favourites:  action.payload}
        
        case ActionTypes.FAVOURITES_LOADING:
            return {...state, isLoading: true, errMess: null, favourites: []}

        case ActionTypes.FAVOURITES_FAILED:
            return {...state, isLoading: false, errMess: action.payload, favourites: []}

        default: 
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `deleteFavourite` and `postFavourite`, too?

Comment: sure! I have uploaded it. Have a look

Comment: Have you checked what the API with the DELETE method returned with? Does it return the correct array with that one item removed?

Comment: yes it correctly removes what i remove but the icon becomes all heart empty (not a favourite means), so i delete one and it works but all the icon becomes with an empty heart even the favourites one, it does not delete all the rest is just the icons, if i refresh the page then whatever is on favourite is shown, or if i click something not on favourite(so i add one item to favourite) then all the icon becomes back normal, showing whats the favourite and what is not.